# Azure Bot Troubleshooting

Tags: azure, web-applications, bots, botframework, azureportal

I have issues with running deployed azure bot.

I've created a simple echo bot based on VS templates. All works locally with emulator.
Now I want to deploy this bot to azure with ARM templates. I use the following resources definition:

```
"resources": [
{
  "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
  "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices",
  "name": "[parameters('azureBotId')]",
  "location": "[parameters('azureBotRegion')]",
  "kind": "azurebot",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('azureBotSku')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('azureBotId')]",
    "iconUrl": "https://docs.botframework.com/static/devportal/client/images/bot-framework-default.png",
    "endpoint": "[parameters('botEndpoint')]",
    "msaAppId": "[parameters('appId')]",
    "msaAppTenantId": "[variables('appType').tenantId]",
    "msaAppMSIResourceId": "[variables('appType').msiResourceId]",
    "msaAppType": "[parameters('appType')]",
    "luisAppIds": [],
    "schemaTransformationVersion": "1.3",
    "isCmekEnabled": false,
    "isIsolated": false
  },
  "dependsOn": []
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": {},
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('webAppHostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
          "value": "[parameters('webAppCurrentStack')]"
        }
      ],
      "phpVersion": "[parameters('webAppPhpVersion')]",
      "netFrameworkVersion": "[parameters('webAppNetFrameworkVersion')]",
      "alwaysOn": "[parameters('webAppAlwaysOn')]",
      "ftpsState": "[parameters('webAppFtpsState')]"
    },
    "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().Id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('webAppHostingPlanName'))]",
    "clientAffinityEnabled": true,
    "virtualNetworkSubnetId": null,
    "httpsOnly": true,
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
  }
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('webAppHostingPlanName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "",
  "tags": {},
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('webAppHostingPlanName')]",
    "workerSize": "[parameters('webAppWorkerSize')]",
    "workerSizeId": "[parameters('webAppWorkerSizeId')]",
    "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('webAppNumberOfWorkers')]",
    "zoneRedundant": false
  },
  "sku": {
    "Tier": "[parameters('webAppSku')]",
    "Name": "[parameters('webAppSkuCode')]"
  }
}
]
```

that I run via:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group $groupName --template-file $armTemplatePath --parameters @$armTemplateParams --parameters  appId=${{ secrets.DEPLOYMENT_AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --parameters webAppName=$webAppName
```

that creates a `bot` and `web app` services on azure. Then I deploy particular web app changes via:

```
  az bot prepare-deploy --lang Csharp --code-dir "." --proj-file-path "Bot.csproj"
  az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "RGName" --name "WebAppName" --src "deploy.zip"
```

that succeded. Now I can open `https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/` and see `Your bot is ready!` page. However, when I try navigating to https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/api/messages in the browser, I see 404 error. Which I assume leads to inability to use `Test in Web Chat` windows in the bot service.

My `appsettings.json`:

```
"MicrosoftAppType": "MultiTenant",
"MicrosoftAppId": "Microsoft App ID from Azure Bot/Configuration",
"MicrosoftAppPassword": "Client Secret value from Azure Bot/Configuration/Manage PAssword",
"MicrosoftAppTenantId": ""
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is it a 404 or a 405? We should be expecting a 405 as the bot doesn't have a GET endpoint it will respond from (only POST).